# Why does adding a UIView to a UITableViewCell result in a crash?

Tags: ios7, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to create a custom UITableViewCell containing a UIView, a UILabel and a UITextField.  Adding a UIView to the TVC is fine, but as soon as I add an IBOutlet to the equation, I get a crash when opening the table view controller that displays the custom cell.  I have researched this for two hours and I still can't find a hint as to why this is happening.  Here's the details:

```c
//MYTextFieldTableViewCell.h
@interface MYTextFieldTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* placeholderLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *layer;
    - (IBAction)textFieldEditingDidEnd:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)textFieldEditingDidBegin:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)textFieldTouchUpInside:(id)sender;
@end
```

I have tried adding the Outlet with Object set to both File's Owner as well as "Text Field Table View Cell" and I get the same outcome.  When I add the IBOutlet, I get the following warning:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'layer' because
>   it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another
>   property.

Finally, the really confusing part is the crash report on the call stack:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType CGColor]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xedb1170'

I'm new to iOS development so I am guessing I am missing the obvious here.  Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: I suspect you have a name collision -- rename your "`layer`" property into something else (e.g. "`tableLayer`").  UIViews do have Core Animation layers, after all.

Comment: your error shows the reference to `NSCFType` which usually refers to an error in memory management. Maybe the memory address that was referencing your UIView is not anymore and you get this error. Could you show us more of the stack trace to see what happens before the crash?

Comment: Michael, you nailed it.  I renamed the property to uiViewLayer and that resolved the problem!